# NiceScroll multiple scrolls

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, nicescroll

I have a bug on my website, I am making a dashboard and I'm using a left navigation type and a middle content. The bug is really annoying me because I can't fix it.

The left navigation uses a scroll and the content window uses a scoll, If i scroll above the left navigation activity feed the scrollbar ends up way out of position and I really want to fix this.

[The link to my website where you can see the bug](http://afgamers.se/Stackoverflow/)

HTML CODE

```
<ul id="NS-02">
        <li><div class="avatar-small"></div></li>
        <li><div class="avatar-small"></div></li>
        <li><div class="avatar-small"></div></li>
        <li><div class="avatar-small"></div></li>
        <li><div class="avatar-small"></div></li>
        <li><div class="avatar-small"></div></li>
        <li><div class="avatar-small"></div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS CODE

```
div.activity-feed {
    background-color: #35383f;
    width: 290px;
    height: 315px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
}
div.activity-header {
    font-size: 7pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #969696;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
ul {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have many mistakes in code.

- `<link/>` as tags should be closed with `/>`.
- `<meta>` tag should be in  section `<html>`
- `<html      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml    xml:lang="sv" lang="sv">`
  missing quotation marks.
- You should use some reset css file for all browsers comaptibilty for
  example http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Here's example created for you, not exact your code, becuase it has serious flaws, it's not worth to change it [EXAMPLE](http://revelier.home.pl/_examples/multiNicescroll/)

You should learn basic before using plugins that's my private opinion.

**EDIT:**

Example is changed, add leftColumn with activity feed box on left and on right content with jquery height and width (left column - window width)
the fastest way to create for you desire I guess.

Peace,

Simon